# How do I find which OS layer (iptables, rp_filter, etc) is dropping a packet?

Tags: networking, firewall, iptables

Let's say that I'm running a ping towards a machine and I see from `tcpdump` that the icmp echo reply is being received at the ethernet port but the `ping` program is not getting it.

So I know that Ubuntu is dropping the packet but is there any good way to find which OS layers is doing it, to my knowledge it can be:

- iptables
- rp_filter
- vlan not matching, etc

So it's there a way to "inject" or "pretend" or "emulate" a packet that tells me  who drops it?
I mean something akin to `ip route get xxx from xxx iff xxx` in the sense that that one tells me that the ip routing table would do for an outgoing packet and I want something that tells me what the kernel will do with a incoming packet.

Is there something like that? if not, what is a good procedure to find out who drops the packet?